# How can I apply this easy derivative on this integral?

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

Im trying to understand a step in a certain proof, this is actually only easy calculus, but somehow I can't wrap my head around it. The equation is given as

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_0^t f(x+(s-t)b,s) \, \text{d}s = f(x,t) + \int_0^t -b \cdot \nabla f(x+(s-t)b,s) \text{d}s.$$

I don't get that, because Im thinking

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_0^t f(x+(s-t)b,s) \, \text{d}s &= \int_0^t \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x+(s-t)b,s) \, \text{d}s \newline
&= \int_0^t -b \cdot \nabla f(x+(s-t)b,s) \text{d}s.
\end{align}

Obviously Im missing something easy here, anyone knows from top of their head?

Cheers

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: To see why your first step is wrong consider the case when $f$ is the constant function $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the integral as a multivariate function
$$ I(A,B,t) := \int_A^B F(s,t)\ ds$$
Then if we set $\psi(t) := (0,t,t)$, $\psi'\equiv (0,1,1)$, and the multivariate chain rule gives
$$ \frac{d}{dt} I\circ \psi(t) = \nabla I(t) \cdot \psi'(t)= 0\times (\partial_A I)(0,t,t)+1\times(\partial_B I)(0,t,t) + 1\times (\partial_t I)(0,t,t) $$
The second term $\partial_B I$ is just $F(s,t)$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, and the last term is the term you thought that should be there, $(\partial_t I)(0,t,t) = \int_0^t \partial_t F(s,t) \ ds$.

In your case $F(s,t) = f(x+(s-t)b,s)$, so we have $\partial_t F(s,t) = -b\cdot \nabla f(x + (s-t)b,s)$ as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Calvin Khor, please tell me friend, whats the need of this $\psi$?

Comment: @MJimitater hm not so sure how to answer that. What do you need, other than it works?  I guess it takes the general configuration $(A,B,t)$ and constrains it to the case where $B=t$ and $A=0$?

Comment: Yes, I see now, thanks!